# why the data element is not changing its value in some function in vuejs and how to make it's value changable?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am accessing these webURLs with the help of axios API in the created() function. In the HTML file I got the index from some v-for handler through a mouseover event and I assigned the value of index to selectedState data element. However it is changing when I see in console box but when I use it to some function it's value remain constant.

Here when I want to use it as the webURL's array index(which should be dynamic according to selectedState) the value of statsJson property remains constant.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
    return {
    webURL:[{
      id:0,URL:"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smlab-niser/CRiAPGraph/master/districts/Andhra%20Pradesh.json?token=AOYHVJ22Y4JWLLUXWXODLRK6ZKARK"
    },
  {
    id:22,URL:"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smlab-niser/CRiAPGraph/master/districts/rajasthan.json?token=AOYHVJ575LRB2FOYBJMVKWK6ZKAVY"
  },
  {
    id:3,URL:"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smlab-niser/CRiAPGraph/master/states.json?token=AOYHVJ2BNIP7L3TMOE66JWK6ZKBRK"
  }
],
    selectedState:0,
    cityJson: null,
    statesJson: null
  }},
  methods:{
    updateDetails:function(index, evt)
    {
      this.selectedState = index
      console.log(this.selectedState)
      console.log(this.statesJson.features[this.selectedState].id)
     }
  },
  
  created () {
    axios.all([axios.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smlab-niser/CRiAPGraph/master/states.json?token=AOYHVJ2BNIP7L3TMOE66JWK6ZKBRK'),
               axios.get(this.webURL[this.selectedState].URL)])
      .then(axios.spread((user1,user2) => (
        console.log(user1.data),
        console.log(this.selectedState),
        console.log(user2.data),
        this.statesJson=user1.data,
        this.cityJson=user2.data
)))
      .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  },
  })
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="tooltip" display="none" style="position: absolute; display: none;"></div>
  <svg id="svg" ref="svg" height="800" width="1600">
   <path class="bar"
     v-for="(state, index) in stateData"
     :d="pathGenerator(state.feature)"
     :style="{
       fill: state.color,
       stroke: 'darkslategray'
     }"
      @mouseover="updateDetails(index,state)"
      @mouseout = "hideTooltip()"
      >
   </path>
   </svg>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code inside `created()` function is only trigger **once**, when the DOM is created and before its fully mounted. In that time, `selectedState` will take the value of 0 as defined in the initial state.

More on Vue lifecycle can be read here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

When user use the mouse to interact, the `updateDetails` function will be called, which update the `selectedState`, however, it not gonna trigger the axios again, that's why the value of `statesJson` remains constant. You need to trigger the axios call to update the `statesJson`.

```
methods:{
    updateDetails:function(index, evt)
    {
      this.selectedState = index;
      this.axiosCall(); // trigger again
     },
    axiosCall() {
       axios.all([axios.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smlab-niser/CRiAPGraph/master/states.json?token=AOYHVJ2BNIP7L3TMOE66JWK6ZKBRK'),
               axios.get(this.webURL[this.selectedState].URL)])
      .then(axios.spread((user1,user2) => (
        console.log(user1.data),
        console.log(this.selectedState),
        console.log(user2.data),
        this.statesJson=user1.data,
        this.cityJson=user2.data
      )))
      .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      })
  },
  
  created () {
    this.axiosCall();
  }
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually I was doing a very silly mistake.

Comment: great, please help mark my post as answer or vote up if it helps you thanks

Comment: can you please answer the one more question if you know about that?